# Using gymnasium play on CartPole makes the cart go left all the time

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to play CartPole on Jupyter Notebook using my keyboard. I'm using the following code from Farama documentation

```
import gymnasium as gym
from gymnasium.utils.play import play

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1", render_mode="rgb_array")
play(env, keys_to_action={"a": 0, "d": 1}, fps=2)
```

However, the cart keeps going to the left despite pressing `d`. How may I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

To play [Cart Pole](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/environments/classic_control/cart_pole/) using your keyboard, it's best to enable key repeats at the OS level, with a "Repeat delay" and "Repeat speed" that are respectively low and fast.

Even though you specified `fps=2`, you need to ensure that you send enough "d" key-pressed events when pressing it down continuously.

Otherwise, you'd have to be *very fast* at pressing "d" up and down...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be familiar with `play`, it is good to test with an environment with simple discrete state space, for example, **[FrozenLake](https://gymnasium.farama.org/environments/toy_text/frozen_lake/#frozen-lake)**.
You can easily check how key-pressing interacts with `play`.

```
env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1", render_mode="rgb_array", is_slippery=False)
play(env, keys_to_action={"a":0, "s":1, "d":2, "w":3}, fps=5)
```

After you succeed to press 's' to make the agent move down, you will notice that the agent looks to the left.
This means that the agent continuously takes 'left' action (which is the first action in the action space) when there is no key input.
For this reason, it's hard to reach goal because it's hard to timing.

Then, you might want to find another environment with noop action: **[CarRacing](https://gymnasium.farama.org/environments/box2d/car_racing/#car-racing)** is that.

```
env = gym.make("CarRacing-v2", render_mode="rgb_array", continuous=False)
play(env, keys_to_action={"a":1, "d":2, "w":3, "s":4}, noop=0, fps=5)
```

The first action of CarRacing is 'Do nothing', thus it is more predictable and easy to control than FrozenLake. If you press down on the "a" or "d" key, you can also see that the car continues to move in the corresponding direction.

Now you can predict how **CartPole** will interact with your key pressing: If you patiently press the "d" key, the cart will go to the right.